# How to test if navigationBar button is enabled/disabled in UI test on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

In my iOS app I've added UI tests, where I need to check if navigationBar button is enabled/disabled at different point of time.

Currently I'm using:

```
XCUIElement* saveButton = self.app.navigationBars[@"TSSIDAddCardView"].buttons[@"Save"];


XCTAssertEqual(saveButton.hittable, YES);
```

However, this always returns YES. The .exists test returns YES as well.

Does anyone knows how to do the proper test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with help of @InsertWittyName I found the solution:

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = self.app.navigationBars[@"TSSIDAddCardView"].buttons[@"Save"];
XCTAssertFalse(saveButton.enabled);
```

Comment: I don't believe this is working because you're getting access to the `UIBarButtonItem`. In your example, `saveButton` is actually still an `XCUIElement`, and that conforms to the `XCUIElementAttributes` protocol, which has an `enabled`/`isEnabled` property. You could test this put printing `[[saveButton class] description]`. Your example only works because of the looseness of Objective-C's dynamic dispatch; it won't work in Swift, however.  Basically, change `UIBarButtonItem *saveButton =` to either `id saveButton =` or `XCUIElement *saveButton =` and you'll find the functionality is the same.

Comment: I'm just curious if you look at the dates before you're making comments...when the post was made. xcode 7.2 was not even released yet...so anything you're writing here was not possible. I might be wrong, but I think I'm right.

Comment: No, I tend not to.  Because that's the design of StackOverflow— it's a knowledge base of Q&As fir the benefit of not only the original poster, but all who may have the issue in the future (unlike a forum— again, which was & is verymuch a primary design goal of SO from day one).  Also, I tend not to write SO Qs or As nearly as often as I find Qs that match my issue, and find an A that helps, comment on them, and/or write an A with my own best-attempt solution.

Comment: In response to your answer being out of date— sorry, that's kind of been an issue with SO for a while now, and only half-solved in some places with version-specific tags.  I write comments for others (like myself) reading the answer in the present-day, not as a reverse-time-capsule for people years ago (yes, I'm being sarcastic, but in Apple's ecosystem, developing software today with Xcode 7 is not feasible).  Also important: I wasn't really writing my comment to you, but as a forewarning to others who may come across your solution and spend time trying it before realizing it no longer works.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure your code was ever safe/sane.  I don't believe you were ever getting a `UIBarButtonItem *` back, and typecasting to the wrong object type has always been a big no-no on Obective-C.  I believe the error I saw is just because newer versions of the compiler have tighter typechecks and will now throw errors when it used to just warn or stay silent.  I believe your code was always errornous; it's just that older compilers would let you shoot yourself in the foot.  This is specifically why I suggested using `id` as the type instead.

Answer (score 7):

[`XCUIElement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement) conforms to [`XCUIElementAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes), which provides [`@property(readonly, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes/1500330-isenabled).

So you can just do this on your `XCUIElement* saveButton`:

<sub>Objective-C</sub>

```
XCTAssertEqual(saveButton.enabled, YES);
```

<sub>Swift</sub>

```
XCTAssertEqual(saveButton.isEnabled, true)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the actual UI component via the `value` property.

With that you can check if it is enabled or not.

Something like:

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = self.app.navigationBars[@"TSSIDAddCardView"].buttons[@"Save"].value;
XCTAssertTrue(saveButton.enabled);
```

Comment: the .value property returns a string by the way, not the UIBarButtonItem object

Comment: However, BOOL saveButton = self.app.navigationBars[@"TSSIDAddCardView"].buttons[@"Save"].enabled - this looks like working

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me (using Xcode 8.3.3).  When I try to do this, I get errors like _“error: property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'id'”_ or _“error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.”_ because the result of `…buttons[@"Save"].value` is an `__NSCFConstantString`.